# Retention Policy / Restoration Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Our company is working on migrating from Box to Office 365, including SharePoint Online.  We will have a retention policy of 3 years set on all of our files.  This means all files with a last modified date of >3 years back will be sent to the recycling bin, including older files that are uploaded via the OneDrive Sync client.

My biggest question is, if these older files are sent to the recycling bin (which has its own 93 day retention period), and I restore these files, what happens once the files are restored?  Does the 3 year retention period get reset on these even though the last modified date doesn’t change, or will they continue to get sent back to the recycling bin?

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, these files will continue to be sent back to the recycling bin.